# How to configure Emacs/VM to decode text/html mails using lynx rather than emacs-w3m?

Tags: emacs, emacs23, lynx

I recently upgrated to Emacs  23.2.1. I am using VM version 8.1.93a to read my email.
I used to change html mail to text via the following line in my vm configuration file:

```
(add-to-list 'vm-mime-type-converter-alist 
'("text/html" "text/plain" "lynx -force_html -dump -stdin"))
```

but under emacs 23 I get the following error message:

```
Inline text/html by emacs-w3m display failed: 
(error "Emacs-w3m of this version does not support 
Emacs 23; try the development version")
```

Searching a bit in Emacs documentation, I thought I had found a solution, by the way of

```
(load-library "mm-decode")
(setq mm-text-html-renderer "lynx")
```

But it seems that vm-8 totally ignores both vm-mime-type-converter-alist  (which is still documented) and mm-text-html-renderer (which is documented, was set to w3m till I set it to lynx). Did I miss something or is vm messed up and I should choose another emacs mail reader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer via some more googling, in the release description of vm-8.1
(http://savannah.c3sl.ufpr.br/viewmail/NEWS)

> ```
>     text/html handling controlled by a new variable
>     `vm-mime-text/html-handler' which is set to 'auto-select by
>     default.  It causes VM to locate the best library among
>     emacs-w3m, external w3m, w3 and lynx to display html
>     internally.  (This replaces the earlier variable
>     `vm-mime-use-w3-for-text/html'.)
> ```

Note that this variable was *not* set to "auto-select" but to "emacs--w3m" by default.
Adding the following to my vm configuration did the trick for me:
      (setq vm-mime-text/html-handler "lynx")
And the yanking of html emails work (contrarily to what happened to me with w3m-emacs)

Comment: Setting `vm-mime-text/html-handler' to 'auto-select asks VM to automatically select the html renderer, in the preference order specified in the NEWS announcement.  So, if your installation has emacs-w3m, it will get set to 'emacs-w3m.  You can override it by setting it to the html renderer of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Try `(setq vm-mime-renderer-for-text/html 'lynx)`.  It had worked for someone using vm 8.0 sometime back, [as seen here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gnu.emacs.vm.info/6pABdLjRMzo).

Comment: Thanks. vm-mime-renderer-for-text/html is not defined in the vm-8 distribution, but a quick grep revealed it in a patch of the contrib folder. Applying the patch via patch lisp/vm-mime.el contrib/vm-mime.el-w3m.patch failed :(